# How do I export the output of Python's built-in help() function

Tags: python, pydoc

I've got a python package which outputs considerable help text from: `help(package)`

I would like to export this help text to a file, in the format in which it's displayed by `help(package)`

How might I go about this?

Comment: Do you know about the [pydoc module](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bit hackish (and there's probably a better solution somewhere), but this works:

```
import sys
import pydoc

def output_help_to_file(filepath, request):
    f = open(filepath, 'w')
    sys.stdout = f
    pydoc.help(request)
    f.close()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return
```

And then...

```
>>> output_help_to_file(r'test.txt', 're')
```

Comment: we can also use this function to get the help of the class of a variable: so if you have a variable v and you would like to write the help of its class, you may write:
output_help_to_file(r'test.txt', v)

Answer (score 23):

pydoc.render_doc(thing) to get thing's help text as a string.  Other parts of pydoc like pydoc.text and pydoc.html can help you write it to a file.

Using the `-w` modifier in linux will write the output to a html in the current directory, for example;

```
pydoc -w Rpi.GPIO
```

Puts all the `help()` text that would be presented from the command `help(Rpi.GPIO)` into a nicely formatted file Rpi.GPIO.html, in the current directory of the shell

Comment: This is actually a bit easier than the selected answer.

Comment: I've found the selected answer to be not very good, using this post, I did a bit of research into pydocs and edited this answer with my exact solution

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I didn't know there was a command line utility to go with it.

Answer (score 8):

An old question but the newer [recommended](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1030160198600548352) generic solution (for Python 3.4+) for writing the output of functions that `print()` to terminal is using `contextlib.redirect_stdout`:

```
import contextlib

def write_help(func, out_file):
    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
            help(func)
```

Usage example:

```
write_help(int, 'test.txt')
```

Comment: does not work with python 3.8.5 on ubuntu 20: the help is still printed on the screen

Comment: @xtof54 Are you sure? It's still recommend for Python 3.9 https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that when I type these commands on my computer, then it does not work. Now, I might have some special configuration I'm not aware of that prevents it to work in my specific case, and may be it's working well for most other people, I don't know...

Answer (score 8):

To get a "clean" text output, just as the built-in help() would deliver, and suitable for exporting to a file or anything else, you can use the following:

```py
>>> import pydoc
>>> pydoc.render_doc(len, renderer=pydoc.plaintext)
'Python Library Documentation: built-in function len in module builtins\n\nlen(obj, /)\n    Return the number of items in a container.\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do help(help) you'll see:

```
Help on _Helper in module site object:

class _Helper(__builtin__.object)
 |  Define the builtin 'help'.
 |  This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).
```

[rest snipped]

So - you should be looking at the pydoc module - there's going to be a method or methods that return what `help(something)` does as a string...

Answer (score 1):

Selected answer didn't work for me, so I did a little more searching and found something that worked on Daniweb. Credit goes to vegaseat. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/20774/starting-python/8#post1306519

```
# simplified version of sending help() output to a file
import sys
# save present stdout
out = sys.stdout
fname = "help_print7.txt"
# set stdout to file handle
sys.stdout = open(fname, "w")
# run your help code
# its console output goes to the file now
help("print")
sys.stdout.close()
# reset stdout
sys.stdout = out
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way

Assuming `help(os)`

Step 1 - In Python Console

```
 import pydoc 
 pydoc.render_doc(os, renderer=pydoc.plaintext)` 
 
 #this will display a string containing help(os) output
```

Step 2 - Copy string

Step 3 - On a Terminal

```
echo "copied string" | tee somefile.txt
```

If you want to write Class information in a text file. Follow below steps

1. Insert pdb hook somewhere in the Class and run file

   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
2. Perform step 1 to 3 stated above

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, just open up a Windows Command Line window, go to the Lib subfolder of your Python installation, and type

python pydoc.py moduleName.memberName > c:\myFolder\memberName.txt

to put the documentation for the property or method memberName in moduleName into the file memberName.txt.  If you want an object further down the hierarchy of the module, just put more dots.  For example

python pydoc.py wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl > c:\myFolder\UltimateListCtrl.txt

to put the documentation on the UltimateListCtrl control in the agw package in the wxPython package into UltimateListCtrl.txt.

Answer (score 0):

pydoc already provides the needed feature, a very well-designed feature that all question-answering systems should have.  The pydoc.Helper.**init** has an output object, all output being sent there.  If you use your own output object, you can do whatever you want.  For example:

class OUTPUT():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.results = []
def write(self,text):
    self.results += [text]
def flush(self):
    pass
def print_(self):
    for x in self.results: print(x)
def return_(self):
    return self.results
def clear_(self):
    self.results = []
```

when passed as

O = OUTPUT()  # Necessarily to remember results, but see below.

help = pydoc.Helper(O)

will store all results in the OUTPUT instance. Of course, beginning with O = OUTPUT() is not the best idea (see below).  render_doc is not the central output point; output is.  I wanted OUTPUT so I could keep large outputs from disappearing from the screen using something like Mark Lutz' "More".  A different OUTPUT would allow you to write to files.

You could also add a "return" to the end of the class pydoc.Helper to return the information you want.  Something like:

if self.output_: return self.output_

should work, or

if self.output_: return self.output.return_()

All of this is possible because pydoc is well-designed.  It is hidden because the definition of help leaves out the input and output arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is via using

> sys module

it opens a data stream between the operation system and it's self , it grab the data from the help module then save it in external file

```
file="str.txt";file1="list.txt"
out=sys.stdout
sys.stdout=open('str_document','w')
help(str)
sys.stdout.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line we can get the output directly and pipe it to whatever is useful.

```
python -m pydoc ./my_module_file.py
```

-- the `./` is important, it tells pydoc to look at your local file and not attempt to import from somewhere else.

If you're on the mac you can pipe the output to `pbcopy` and paste it into a documentation tool of your choice.

```bash
python -m pydoc ./my_module_file.py | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a tiny script that calls the help() you want to capture
and run it from the command line with output redirection.