# In Python3, how do I get the output of "help()" function in to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a list of the built-in function names of Python3, which I can get from `help(__builtins__)`.

I thought `grep` the fetching results of `help(__builtins__)` would do.

Something like below in bash:

```
$ python3 -c "help(__builtins__)" | grep -E "^\s{4}[a-z]+\("
```

So, first I tried to capture the help function's results into a variable like below. But didn't work.

```py
>>> result = help(__builtins__)
>>> print(result)
none
```

Since the "[`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#help)" function was intended for an interactive use, it launched the help page and couldn't get the output.

I googled with "[python3 how do i get the output of help function](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=python3+how+do+i+get+the+output+of+help+function)" and referenced the below 2 article.

- [Getting the docstring from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function) @ StackOverflow
- [How do I export the output of Python's built-in help() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265603/how-do-i-export-the-output-of-pythons-built-in-help-function) @ StackOverflow

But didn't work for me.

```py
>>> print(__builtins__.__doc__)
Built-in functions, exceptions, and other objects.

Noteworthy: None is the `nil' object; Ellipsis represents `...' in
slices.print(__builtins__.__doc__)
```

There's a good chance that I couldn't understand the answers of the above questions. But as a Python beginner, these didn't fully address my question.

Before doing `grep` and all, is there any way to get the `help` function's results into a variable rather than using `exec`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager to capture the output to a file like object from [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#help) function.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Wow! thanks! `from contextlib import redirect_stdout` and using `with redirect_stdout(f):` I got the preferred same results as `$ python3 -c "help(__builtins__)"`. Now I can go forward to `grep` the results! I would like to answer my own how I ended, but it seems that my question is a duplicate and is locked.